# How would you add constraints to this UML Database Model diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, uml

I am drawing my first UML Database Model diagrams and I am having some questions. What is good practice for adding constraints to my tables? Would you move the PKs and FKs below the line, where methods are usually written in a DCD, and should constraints such as NOT NULL also be added below or simply written besides the specific column name? E.g. `Date : DateTime2 NOT NULL` in `SERVICETYPE`

[image]

- Primary keys are underscored
- Foreign keys are marked in red

Comment: What profile are you using to extend UML with database notions?

Comment: @JimL. Mic Sorry - English is not my native language. I am not quite sure I understand your question fully. The diagram is drawn in Microsoft Visio

Comment: @Aleksandar what Jim was meaning is that <<PK>> and <<FK>> are not standard UML and  are necessarily defined in a "profile", like http://agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#TablesEntitiesViews or similar ones

Comment: Underscore is reserved to mark static attributes. Not a good idea, so.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, in plain UML when a class has a property, its default multiplicity is 1, meaning each instance has exactly one value.  If you would provide for the possibility for sole properties of having no value, you should use a multiplicity `[0..1]`.

Since NULL in SQL corresponds to the absence of a value, you'd not have to say to specify NOT NULL in your model.

Now, plain UML does not define database modelling stereotypes like «PK» and «FK». UML allows to define such language extensions using a "profile", like for example [this one](https://agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html#Keys). Such profiles often define other database specific stereotypes, like for example «NOT NULL» and «NULLABLE». So the answer in your case depends on the UML profile you are using for modelling the database physical model.

Alternatively, you may also simply use a constraint such as `{not null}`.

Comment: I see - the design choice of where you should put constraints seems to be arbitrarily chosen as long as the finished diagramme is intuitively and easily readable.

Thank you for your answer.